# MySQL Workbench can not show secondary sidebar

Tags: mysql-workbench

on Virtubox Ubuntu 21.04, MySQL Workbench mysql-workbench-community_8.0.26-1ubuntu21.04_amd64.deb, the secondary sidebar panel, namely the SQL Additions panel can not be displayed, there is only a blink after click on the top right icon as labelled below, same thing happened after View --> Panels --> show secondary sidebar.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution after poking around for hours, hopefully can help someone out.

```
sudo nano ~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml
```

ctrl + w to search for 'secondary', go line:

```
<value type="int" key="DbSqlEditor:SecondarySidebarWidth">1</value>
```

change the value 1 to the width you prefer, e.g. 280
ctrl + x to save and quit nano

open mysql workbench, click on the show secondary sidebar button or from the view --> Panels --> show secondary sidebar, should be working now.

Comment: lifesaver :D :D

Comment: I have to set `SecondarySidebarHidden` value to `1` before saving. If it was set to `0` the modification was overriden when opening the application.